`Purchases.purchasePackage` keeps reopening purchase popup
I'm using React Native (Expo) and I want to integrate RevenueCat. I am following the guide documentation provided by RevenueCat to set it up:

https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart
https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/getting-started/making-purchases
https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/test-and-launch/sandbox/apple-app-store

I have created a Sandbox account in App Store Connect, but when I test a purchase in iOS Simulator, the Purchases.purchasePackage() logic does not exit.
try {
  console.log("START");
  const {customerInfo} = await Purchases.purchasePackage(purchasePackage);
  console.log({customerInfo});

  if (typeof customerInfo.entitlements.active[ENTITLEMENT_ID] !== "undefined") {
    navigation.goBack();
  }
} catch (e: any) {
  if (e.code === Purchases.PURCHASES_ERROR_CODE.PURCHASE_CANCELLED_ERROR) {
    Alert.alert("Error purchasing package", e.message);
  }
  console.log("CATCH");
} finally {
  setIsPurchasing(false);
  console.log("FINALLY");
}

In other words, "START" is printed, but {customInfo} is not. Also, "CATCH" and "FINALLY" are not printed.
The purchase popup below keeps opening and not closing, which seems to be the cause. It keeps reopening after completing the purchase:

What can I check? Thank you for your help.
